# Repeatedly removing and replacing the occurence of a substring from the input string code is not working

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I've been working on this problem:

> Functions – Remove foo
>
> Write a program to find the new string after repeatedly removing the occurence of the substring foo from the input string using functions by repeatedly replacing each occurence of 'foo' by 'oof'.
>
> Refer function specifications for the function details.
>
> The function accepts a pointer to a string.
>
> ```
> void manipulate(char * a)
> ```
>
> Input and Output Format:
>
> Input consists of a string. Assume that all characters in the string are lowercase letters and the maximum length of the string is 100.
>
> Refer sample input and output for formatting specifications.
>
> All text in bold corresponds to input and the rest corresponds to output.
>
> Sample Input and Output :
>
> ```
> Enter the input string
>
> akhfoooo
>
> The output string is akhoooof
> ```
>
> Function Definitions:
>
> ```
> void manipulate (char * a)
> ```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void manipulate (char *a){
    int i;
    char b[3]="foo";
    for (i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        if (strncmp(a+i,b,3)==0){
            a[i]='o';
            a[i+1]='o';
            a[i+2]='f';
            manipulate (a);
        } 
    }
 printf ("%s",a);}
int main(){
    char string[50];
    printf ("Enter the input string\n");
    scanf ("%s",string);
    manipulate (string);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to edit this code in a manner that it gives the right output?

Comment: 'char b[3]="foo";' - not a string.

Comment: Did you do any debugging, eg. printffing out the value of 'i' if a match is found?

Comment: 'please don't downvote rr close this question I beg you all please' will pretty much guarantee down and close votes, whether your question deserves it or not:(

Comment: You are entirely correct that the other question about this exact same assignment has a different issue. You could have avoided the problem by following the SO guidelines on how to ask about simple debugging issues. At a minimum, you should present both the desired behaviour and the behaviour of your code, along with a description of how the differ (if necessary). If the question focusses on the code issue and not the programming task, then it will be compared with other similar code issues instead of being compared with other similar tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Print out the manipulated string in main when manipulate returns. If you print the string in every call to manipulate, you will get what you see, which is all of the intermediate results one after another.

Also, you really should print out a newline at the end of every printf (unless you know for sure that the next printf should be on the same line. So your printf call should look like this:

```
printf("%s\n", string);
```

Comment: Could you please write the corrected code? I couldn't get you completely.

Comment: @"programmer": move line 14 to just after line 19.

Comment: I am using this code now: https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/418168

Comment: But on the coding platform I'm working on

Comment: Any idea why testcases may be failing?

Comment: What testcases?

Comment: I mean, you can enter strings longer than 49 chars and overflow the input buffer - that could be one of them?

Comment: I'm sorry but the testcases are not shown

Comment: @programmer: if the maximum input has length 100, why did you decide to provide a buffer of length 50?? While you can't see the test cases, it'd reasonable to assume that at least one will be the maximum length (which requires a buffer of length 101, by the way).